# How do I use Google Protocol Buffers with a C++ client and a C# WCF service?

Tags: wcf, protocol-buffers

Several questions:

1. How do I get my C# WCF service to use Protocol Buffers?
2. How do I write a C++ client for a WCF service?
3. How do I get that C++ client to use Protocol Buffers when talking to the WCF service.

There seems to be lots of tiny snippets of information out there, but nobody appears to have pulled it all together in one place.

Answer (score 0):

For questions 1 and 3, I do not think that WCF supports Protocol Buffers, REST is probably the closest thing that you have in WCF. You could either use REST, or a REST layer between the client and the server using Protocol Buffers.

Question 2 in covered in this stackoverflow question: [Create WCF service for unmanaged C++ clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686452/create-wcf-service-for-unmanaged-c-clients)

Comment: I actually had a proper go at this the other week. And I almost got it working, except that I was using MSMQ and it doesn't like it when the contract uses something other than Message<T>. Or something; it was a week or two ago.