# How to connect a C++ program to a WCF Service?

Tags: c++, wcf

In the place I work there are some software written in C# and some written in C++ (the most important ones). Some time ago we decided it would be a good idea to track any possible problem in the software, by sending stack trace and exception information over a web service. So I came with a WCF Service, that gets the information and store them on a database and send an automatic e-mail. It worked, we had to secure it through password, it's done, but now I want our other software, the one written in C++, to use this webservice (this software is used both on windows and linux, so we can't just make a call to another software in the user machine).

I've googled about it, and found this [tutorial](http://www.blinnov.com/2008/01/22/wcf-service-unmanaged-client/en/) on how to use [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html), which so far didn't help me very much (lots of errors, it is not very detailed, and the web.config file is impossible to read). I was wondering if is there any other way to achieve this. In adition, since I'm using authentication on my webservice, it now has a wsHttpBinding (which AFAIK isn't supported by [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html)).

Can  you guys help me out?

Comment: I have the same problem. It is Microsoft's best interest that you won't be able to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your WCF service is in C# with .NET, and the only issue is getting the C++ application to be able to talk to it, one way is to follow the advice in [REST / SOAP Endpoints for a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186631/rest-soap-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service) and related articles.

Your C# programs continue to have the full SOAP access to your service.
Your C++ programs could do something like this for REST access:

- "Browse" to the HTTP GET URL for the service command you wanted.
- Then toss (or parse and use) whatever response came back.

It is a pretty minimal change to your WCF service to offer both SOAP and REST.
The REST ability opens your service to JavaScript as well as C++ clients.

You may need to restrict the interface to simple data, or class objects that are easy to parse in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Will the machines running the C++ applications have the .NET Framework installed?

Check out: [Create WCF service for unmanaged C++ clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686452/create-wcf-service-for-unmanaged-c-clients)

Comment: Since this software can be used on linux, I can't be sure about it.