# Consume c# WCF Service in c++

Tags: c#, c++, web-services, wcf, embedded

I have a solution with 3 projects. 1 is a c# Console App which acts as the WCF Host, the 2nd is the c# WCF Service Library and my third is a UI which is generated using XAML Tools for Windows Embedded from a project in Blend, so it generates my UI with c++ files.

My question is, how do I make use of my WCF Service in my UI project. I have read a few articles online about consuming wcf services but still dont understand what is required, all I want to do is call my WCF Functions from the UI and pass values to them,

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Nick

Comment: To get started with .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277373/how-to-connect-a-c-program-to-a-wcf-service

Comment: You will need to make your WCF service RESTFUL. Then each methods have a XML Soap definition. All you have to do is build the XML string definition of the method "X" and send it to the wcf service on the RESTFUL endpoint address you have given that method i.e. 'http:\\...\myservice.svc\GetContact' and the response is the XML result (or json if you changed it). Then parse the xml to find the node you want in the data it returned.

Comment: @Franck Hi, would you be able to give an example of this?

Comment: i don't have one on hand but here's a [very good example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services). it works well for 3.5 and 4.0 WCf

Comment: @Franck Thanks Franck, I'll post a full solution when I've solved it.