# Can I use C++ to connect to a WCF bound using netTcpBinding?

Tags: c++, wcf, c#-4.0

I've got a service hosed in a Windows Service (using ServiceHost) that uses NetTcpBinding. We want to add support for Linux and Mac. Is there an existing library for C++ that could connect to a service that's using NetTcpBinding?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can find similar question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686452/create-wcf-service-for-unmanaged-c-clients)

One of the answer suggest that you can build a C# application and use C++ bridge dll to bridge gap between your unmanaged C++ code and the managed WCF code written in C#.