# Native C++ Client Getting data from WCF Web Service

Tags: c#, c++, mfc

Hi I have a native C++ Application (client) which needs to get data from a WCF web service. Could someone please give me a detailed code on how I can do that.
I have tried many solutions from the site but none of then work as they are not very descriptive and I am new to this field.
Thank you

Comment: This might be helpful [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686452/create-wcf-service-for-unmanaged-c-clients](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686452/create-wcf-service-for-unmanaged-c-clients)

Comment: Do you have .Net runtime available on the clients? What WCF bindings are you using? There are lots of ways to solve this problem but they depend on a lot of variables.