# Calling a C# opeartion with 'Out' from a managed C++ code

Tags: wcf, visual-c++, c#-4.0, c++-cli

Hi
I have a WCF web serive which has an opeartion i need to call from a native C++ apllication. I have a bridge managed DLL which works, but I am having truoble with calling a WCF operation which has an OUT object.

The C# opearation:

`void DoWork(string indxNum, out ErrorWarningsData objerrc)`

Here ErrorWarningsData is a class in the C# Web Service.

This is how my Managed C++ code looks like :

`gcroot<Binding^> binding1 = gcnew WSHttpBinding();`

`gcroot<EndpointAddress^> address1 = gcnew EndpointAddress(gcnew String("http://usatondevlas1.na.praxair.com/Build15/ResourceCenterSVC/ResourceCenter.svc"));`

`gcroot<HelloServiceClient::ServiceReference2::ResourceCenterServiceContractClient^> client = gcnew HelloServiceClient::ServiceReference2::ResourceCenterServiceContractClient(binding1,address1);`

`gcroot<HelloServiceClient::ServiceReference2::ErrorWarningsData^> objEWData = gcnew HelloServiceClient::ServiceReference2::ErrorWarningsData;`

But when I try to call the DoWork Method from the WCF Service  I get an error .

This is what I tried :

`client->DoWork("4278779",[Out] objEWData );`
Also tried,
`client->DoWork("4278779",[Out] ^% objEWData );`
And,
`client->DoWork("4278779",[Out] % objEWData );`

Could some one please tell me how to access the oject with 'OUT'.
I could find some examples to access [Out] for int and string but none for objects

PS: I followed the following to link to connect the WCF service to the native appliaction
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686452/create-wcf-service-for-unmanaged-c-clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using gcroot in these cases.  You can just do:

```
WSHttpBinding ^ binding1 = gcnew WSHttpBinding(); 
EndpointAddress ^ address1 = gcnew EndpointAddress(gcnew String ("http://usatondevlas1.na.praxair.com/Build15/ResourceCenterSVC/ResourceCenter.svc"));
HelloServiceClient::ServiceReference2::ResourceCenterServiceContractClient ^ client = gcnew HelloServiceClient::ServiceReference2::ResourceCenterServiceContractClient(binding1,address1);
HelloServiceClient::ServiceReference2::ErrorWarningData ^ objEWData = gcnew HelloServiceClient::ServiceReference2::ErrorWarningsData;
client->DoWork("4278779", objEWData);
```

Comment: I tried it , but it still throws an exception when I call the method `client ->DoWork("4278778",objEWData)`

Comment: "still throws an exception"?  You never mentioned it throwing an exception before.  If it compiles, it looks like your question is answered--an exception occurring would indicate you are using the method incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any extra markup in order to pass something as an out parameter in C++/CLI. The semantics are similar to passing by reference in native C++.

Comment: I initialize the object using gcroot, So I get an error saying cannot convert from gcroot<T> to <HelloServiceClient::ServiceReference2::ErrorWarningsData^%>

Comment: gcroot does not have a converstion operator to "T^%".  It only returns a copy of T (which should be fine since T is a "pointer type" anyways.  If you want the gcroot variable to point to the new T that is returned by the method, you'll have to have temporary variable of T^ that is passed into the method, and then assign that to your gcroot<T> variable.