# NetNamedPipeBinding between C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, named-pipes, netnamedpipebinding

I've seen that NetNamedPipeBinding exists in C# and in C++ ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx)) and I would like to know if it's possible to use it to transmit datas between a C++ program and a C# application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your C++ compiler is a recent version of Visual C++, with all the extensions to support writing managed code, then you can use WCF easily to pass data between a C++ program and a C# application.

If your C++ compiler doesn't support managed code extensions, you can still do it but it is a lot of work, because the WCF channel stack uses some layered proprietary protocols for message framing, security negotiation and message encoding, which you would need to reimplement on the C++ side if you can't use the managed implementation provided by WCF. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767072/how-do-i-call-a-wcf-method-from-c-using-named-pipes#comment16081273_11767072) for the kind of issues which arise.

If you can't do managed C++ it is often much easier to forego some of the benefits provided by WCF and, depending on your requirements, either to:

- use a managed COM-visible wrapper around a C# WCF service, consumed as a COM server in the C++ code; or
- roll your own IPC mechansim using a named pipe directly, calling the WIn32 APIs on the C++ side and using the System.IO.Pipes types on the C# side.

Comment: Yeah it wasn't that difficult using WCF! the only problem was that there is so little documentation about NetNamedPipeBinding in C++ that I had a really hard time to figure how to make it work, but then it was really easy!

Answer (score 2):

There's a good example here showing how to do IPC (Inter-Process Communication) between C++ and C#.

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34073/Inter-Process-Communication-IPC-Introduction-and-S