# Unmanaged C++ Client for WCF Service?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, wcf

Firstly, let me point to this previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686452/create-wcf-service-for-unmanaged-c-clients). I understand, there are overlaps, but I have a few more specific questions. I'm new to WCF/C# so thanks for your patience.

- I have SOAP Service implemented in C#.
- I want to write a Client for this service in C++, and integrate the client with an already existing C++(Unmanaged) Project.

I tried following the steps described in this:[Walkthrough: Accessing an XML Web Service Using C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290758%28v=vs.71%29.aspx);  but ran across this issue-

- Do not have any option to add Service Reference either in project tab, or when I right click on project(VS2010 Professional). (WHY?)

Is it theoretically possible to write a client in only C++ without creating a dll bridge, writing a wrapper, or using the MSXML COM library?

Any solution would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding SOAP, there are many libraries available if you just search a little. You can use one of them to connect to the server.

Comment: I just tried using a gSOAP client to connect to the WCF server...but it doesn't seem to be working. Could you suggest any alternative, or redirect me to a link that can point me in the right direction?