# How do I make a windows service installer from visual studio 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-services, installation

How do I make a windows service installer from visual studio 2008?

Comment: Which step are you stuck at? Are you looking for a general tutorial, or is there something in particular you're not able to do?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Microsoft KB that gives you the steps:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317421

If you're looking for something particular, please update your question with some more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C#, follow the solution I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-to-create-a-windows-service/593803#593803) beginning at step #6.  And if you're interested in how to have the Windows service install itself (as opposed to using InstallUtil.exe), follow the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195478/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-start-right-after-the-installation/1195621#1195621) (kudos to [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) for this idea).