# Installing a self-developed Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm trying to deploy a service that I wrote.  Here's the InstallLog file:

```
Installing assembly 'c:\Users\brwatson\Development\Projects\TweetLinks\TweetLinkQueue\bin\Debug\TweetLinkQueue.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole = 
   assemblypath = c:\Users\brwatson\Development\Projects\TweetLinks\TweetLinkQueue\bin\Debug\TweetLinkQueue.exe
   logfile = c:\Users\brwatson\Development\Projects\TweetLinks\TweetLinkQueue\bin\Debug\TweetLinkQueue.InstallLog
Installing service TweetLinkService...
Creating EventLog source TweetLinkService in log Application...
Rolling back assembly 'c:\Users\brwatson\Development\Projects\TweetLinks\TweetLinkQueue\bin\Debug\TweetLinkQueue.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole = 
   assemblypath = c:\Users\brwatson\Development\Projects\TweetLinks\TweetLinkQueue\bin\Debug\TweetLinkQueue.exe
   logfile = c:\Users\brwatson\Development\Projects\TweetLinks\TweetLinkQueue\bin\Debug\TweetLinkQueue.InstallLog
Restoring event log to previous state for source TweetLinkService.
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the System.Diagnostics.EventLogInstaller installer.
System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the installation. This exception will be ignored and the rollback will continue. However, the machine might not fully revert to its initial state after the rollback is complete.
```

As you can see, it's not working.  I am not sure how to proceed, and have hit the wall with Bing and Google.  I have set the Account to LocalSystem for the serviceProcessInstaller1.  The code compiles fine, but now I would like to run the thing...any ideas?  I am an administrator on my box, and I am running the command:

InstallUtil TweetLinkQueue.exe

from the VS2008 admin console.

UPDATED WITH /ShowCallStack option

Call Stack

```
An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all eve
nt logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.FindSourceRegistration(String source, String m
achineName, Boolean readOnly)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(String source, String machineName
)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInstaller.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller.Install(IDictionary savedSt
ate)
   at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.Configuration.Install.TransactedInstaller.Install(IDictionary saved
State)
```

and here is the constructor:

```
public TweetLinkService()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (!EventLog.SourceExists("TweetLinkQueue"))
    {
        EventLog.CreateEventSource("TweetLinkQueue", "Log");

        TweetLinksLog.Source = "TweetLinkQueue";
        TweetLinksLog.Log = "Log";

        TweetLinksLog.WriteEntry("Log Created!");
    }
}
```

UPDATED with ENtry Point:

```
namespace TweetLinkQueue
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new TweetLinkService() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any additional info if you run installutil with the /ShowCallStack option?

Comment: The log file info is in the above question.

Comment: Does the user you are trying to install the service with have permissions to write to the Security event log?

Comment: From the EventLog.SourceExists docs: "In Windows Vista, users do not have permission to access the security log; therefore, a SecurityException is thrown."  Are you definitely running from an elevated command prompt?  (Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, but the symptoms do seem to match...!)

Comment: For the edification of all, the described problem has nothing to do with the code in a constructor or an entry point.  InstallUtil does not execute this code; it is only executed when the service actually starts.  InstallUtil uses reflection to figure out things about the service in order to install it on the system.  So for simply installing the service, it is important to make sure that the service has been configured properly.  Once the service is installed, you can work on testing/fixing the code.

Comment: Thank you Matt for clarity...I was providing information in advance.  In reading what you and others have written, I have an access problem.  However, the local user has Admin rights on the box, so I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Brandon: under Vista, there's a difference between having Admin rights and running *with* Admin rights: by default, UAC constrains admin users to have only standard rights (mangled explanation but I hope it makes kinda sense!).  Try right-clicking the command prompt shortcut, choosing Run as administrator (which removes the UAC restriction) and re-running installutil from this elevated command prompt.

Comment: The problem could be that you do not have permission to access the Event Viewer at all, in which case, you require more permissions in order to enable writing to the event log.  Or it could just be that you do not have permission to mess with the Application log of the Event Viewer.  Try creating your own log by referring to the example I listed in my answer (i.e., step 9).  That may fix it for you.

Comment: @Matt, I basically copied your code from Step 9...it's not solving the problem.  Bummer.

Comment: Sounds like it's a permissions problem then.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure what your specific problem is.  It looks to me like the problem occurs while creating the EventLog source.  Double-check that you've done that part correctly.  You can reference the step-by-step [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-to-create-a-windows-service/593803#593803).  **EDIT:  SPECIFICALLY LOOK AT STEP 9.**  The problem may be occuring because you're messing with the Application log instead of one specific to your application.

There's nothing wrong with using InstallUtil, but if you need to install your service on a foreign machine, InstallUtil is not guaranteed to be there.  You can follow this step-by-step to make your Windows service executable install/uninstall itself without the need of InstallUtil.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195478/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-start-right-after-the-installation/1195621#1195621) for those instructions.

Answer (score 131):

I was just having this issue and it was because I wasn't running my visual studio command prompt as an administrator.

Comment: this explains why it worked on my machine but not on production

Comment: I created a BAT file for installing the service and I was running the BAT file as an Administrator (right click on BAT file and click "run as administrator" option) but it was not working. In order to make it work I "run as Administrator" a commannd line prompt (cmd.exe) instead of the BAT file. Then, I installed it manually and it worked.

Comment: Thanks! this was my problem and with Run as Admin on CMD it work fine !

Comment: This is the answer for sure

Answer (score 8):

To solve this issue right click on your  Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt and click run as administrator then you run your command like installutil C:\mcWebService\bin\Debug\mcWebService.exe
then it will show you successful message.
Hope this will solve your solution.

Answer (score 2):

The LocalSystem account doesn't normally have permission to read the Security event log (or to create event sources for that matter).

The easiest and safest solution is to create an event source installation program that you can run under your own administration-level credentials on any machine for which you'll want to run this. It might be even worth trying this as a simple test, just to see if your account has the permission to do this.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        EventLog.CreateEventSource("TestSource", "Application");
    }
}
```

If you execute that, does it succeed? You can check it by looking at the Application log's properties and browsing the Event sources on its Filter tab.

Alternately, since services have to be installed anyway, you could add an `EventLogInstaller` (which is misnamed - it's really an 'EventSourceInstaller' that will create `EventLogs` as needed) to the assembly instead of using `EventLog.CreateEventSource` in the service's constructor.

Comment: Yep.  See the code following step 9 at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-to-create-a-windows-service/593803#593803 for an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was a window was popping to enter credentials and I was entering my username without the domain. Once I entered **domain\username** all was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same unexplainable errors when installing windows services.
In our case the user was the problem.

Installing the server with the administrator-user worked, but not for a local admin. This, however, is not a preferred solution, so we used this information to create a different user that could install the service.