# Installation failure of Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

I have made a Windows Service, when I tried to install it, I get this message :

> D:\workspace\TestWindowsService\TestWindowsService\bin\Debug>InstallUtil.exe
>   TestWindowsService.exe Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation
>   utility Version 4.6.1586.0 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All
>   rights reserved.
>
> Running a transacted installation.
>
> Beginning the Install phase of the installation. See the contents of
>   the log file for the
>   D:\workspace\TestWindowsService\TestWindowsService\bin\Debug\TestWindowsService.exe
>   assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   D:\workspace\TestWindowsService\TestWindowsService\bin\Debug\TestWindowsService.InstallLog.
>   Installing assembly
>   'D:\workspace\TestWindowsService\TestWindowsService\bin\Debug\TestWindowsService.exe'.
>   Affected parameters are:    logtoconsole =    logfile =
>   D:\workspace\TestWindowsService\TestWindowsService\bin\Debug\TestWindowsService.InstallLog
>   assemblypath =
>   D:\workspace\TestWindowsService\TestWindowsService\bin\Debug\TestWindowsService.exe
>   Installing service Scheduler... Creating EventLog source Scheduler in
>   log Application...
>
> An exception occurred during the Install phase.
>   System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some
>   or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
>
> The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning. See the contents
>   of the log file for the
>   D:\workspace\TestWindowsService\TestWindowsService\bin\Debug\TestWindowsService.exe
>   assembly's progress. The file is located at
>   D:\workspace\TestWindowsService\TestWindowsService\bin\Debug\TestWindowsService.InstallLog.
>   Rolling back assembly
>   'D:\workspace\TestWindowsService\TestWindowsService\bin\Debug\TestWindowsService.exe'.
>   Affected parameters are:    logtoconsole =    logfile =
>   D:\workspace\TestWindowsService\TestWindowsService\bin\Debug\TestWindowsService.InstallLog
>   assemblypath =
>   D:\workspace\TestWindowsService\TestWindowsService\bin\Debug\TestWindowsService.exe
>   Restoring event log to previous state for source Scheduler. An
>   exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLogInstaller installer.
>   System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some
>   or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
>   An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the installation.
>   This exception will be ignored and the rollback will continue.
>   However, the machine might not fully revert to its initial state after
>   the rollback is complete.
>
> The Rollback phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed. The installation failed, and the
>   rollback has been performed.

I couldn't find what to do from this message. How can I fix my problem? Thanks.

Comment: Run the command prompt (cmd) in administrator mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing a self-developed Windows Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580023/installing-a-self-developed-windows-service)

Comment: @gypsyCoder I installed the service but it doesn't appear on Services list. How can I make it appear on the list? Thanks.

Comment: @jason you can follow this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx