# Installing Windows Service programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-services

How do I install a Windows Service programmatically without using installutil.exe?

Comment: And not using any other 3rd party installers?

Comment: yep....i wish i could use a function like installservice() and when i double click the windowsservice.exe,it checks whether its installed,if not installed,it installs itself.

Comment: that is one good function :):)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can install the service by adding this code (in the program file, Program.cs) to install itself when run from the commandline using specified parameters:

```
/// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (System.Environment.UserInteractive)
            {

                if (args.Length > 0)
                {
                    switch (args[0])
                    {
                        case "-install":
                            {
                                ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                                break;
                            }
                        case "-uninstall":
                            {
                                ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MyService() };
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Although this is a clear and suitable way to do that instead of using "low level" advapi32.dll, the framework documentation says "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.". But I still prefer "ManagedInstallerClass" and the risks of future incompatibilities in new .net versions. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.configuration.install.managedinstallerclass)

Comment: I wonder, if I call `ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(srvExe)` from another console app, would this app wait till `InstallHelper` exits (with installation finnished)? Thanks.

Comment: Could be new in recent framework versions (4.8), but the System.Configuration.Install namespace, and hence the ManagedInstaller class, exists only in debug builds.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: for debug builds you can include a reference to System.Configuration.Install.dll, for release builds System.Configuration.dll must also be added.

Comment: I had a different way, I have been trying to make to work, with no luck. this was the only way I got service installation to work

Answer (score 11):

I use the method from the following CodeProject article, and it works great.

[Windows Services Can Install Themselves](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/WinSvcSelfInstaller.aspx)

Comment: Great link; however, it references a link written by Mahmoud Nasr that is broken.  I used this and it works for me.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: I wonder, if I call `ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(srvExe)` from another console app, would this app wait till `InstallHelper` exits (with installation finnished)? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I install and uninstall my Windows Service via the command line, e.g., `MyWindowsService.exe -install` and `MyWindowsService.exe -uninstall`, to avoid using `installutil.exe` myself.  I've written a set of instructions for how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195478/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-start-right-after-the-installation/1195621#1195621).

Comment: The OP asked how to do this programmatically, not via the command line.

Comment: My solution is a programmatic solution that is accessed via the command line the same way the accepted answer is.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment bc of missing reputation, but regarding Mark Redman's Solution - If you wonder you cannot find your key in the given path, checkout the `WOW6432Node`

### From [AdvancedInstaller](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/registry-wow6432-node.html):

"The `Wow6432Node` registry entry indicates that you are running a 64-bit Windows version.

The operating system uses this key to display a separate view of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE for 32-bit applications that run on 64-bit Windows versions. When a 32-bit application writes or reads a value under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\<company>\<product>` subkey, the application reads from the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\<company>\<product> subkey.`

A registry reflector copies certain values between the 32-bit and 64-bit registry views (mainly for COM registration) and resolves any conflicts using a "last-writer-wins" approach."

Answer (score 0):

None of the above work with .Net Core, however see my answer here on a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76732404/440503 using System.Diagnostics.Process to start `sc.exe`.

Use sc.exe from a command line with no arguments to find its usage.