# How can I install a windows service onto a machine that doesn't have Visual Studio installed?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

The only way to install windows-service I know is using "**Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt**", Is there a way to install windows-service on a machine which isn't having Visual Studio installed (assume that .Net version 2.X is installed.)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

you can do it with `installUtil` which resides in the .net framework folder (on my machine it's C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727).

Comment: For my .Net 4.5 service I had to use the InstallUtil.exe located in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319. When I tried to use the one in the v2.0.50727 directory I got an error saying "The assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded."

Comment: @deadlydog The original question was regarding .Net version 2, but you are correct that you need to use the version of `installUtil` that matches the framework version that the service is built for.

Comment: @giorgi It will depend which .Net framework you set your project to target. If your project targets .Net 4.0, but the server only has .Net 3.5 installed, then you won't be able to use installUtil for it, and even if you could get it installed, it wouldn't run. The server needs to at least have the .Net version (or greater) that your project is set to target.

Answer (score 8):

You can install Windows Services as an MSI. Create the MSI as a normal Project attached to your Service Project.

In your Service Project Create an Installer Class and add the components serviceInstaller and serviceProcessInstaller and configure as required. Add the Project Output from the Service Project to the MSI Project, Set the Custom Actions of the MSI Project for Install, Commit, Rollback and Uninstall to the Output of the Service Project.

Alter the MSI Project in any other way as desired, build the MSI, then you will be able to install your Service to any Windows machine without VS.NET or by using the InstallUtil utility application. The MSI will also handle the Uninstall etc.

There are properties of the serviceProcessInstaller component which you can set for the Account to run the Service under, the serviceInstaller contains properties which can be set such as the Service Name. You will have to set the ServiceName and its Parent, MSDN will provide good information on how to use both of these components.

Comment: "Set" the custom actions?

Answer (score 7):

Relevant MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha%28VS.80%29.aspx

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\installutil.exe yourproject.exe
```

You don't need to have Visual Studio installed for this to work.

Answer (score 5):

Yep, [`installutil.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95(VS.80).aspx) works nicely, but I got tired of having to remember to start the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt in order to use it.  Invariably, I'd open an ordinary console only to realize that the `installutil.exe` location was not part of the path.

Fortunately, the `installutil.exe` is a wrapper around a set of reflection calls.  From MSDN,

> `Installutil.exe` uses reflection to
>   inspect the specified assembly and
>   find all `Installer` types with the
>   `RunInstallerAttribute` set to true. The
>   tool then executes either the Install
>   Method or the Uninstall Method on each
>   instance of the `Installer` type.

What this means is that it is possible to add code to the Windows service to have it install and uninstall itself.  By doing so, I no longer require `installutil.exe` or the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt to run it.

I have provided a step-by-step guide for how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195478/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-start-right-after-the-installation/1195621#1195621).  The `-install` option installs the Windows service and starts it.  Conversely, the `-uninstall` option stops the service and uninstalls it.

Answer (score 3):

With visual studio command prompt:

```
installutil /i fullfilepathtoservice.exe
```

Without visual studio command prompt:

```
C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322 installutil /i fullfilepathtoservice.exe
```

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Open a command prompt (cmd) and type

> help sc

and

> sc create

In additon the installutil.exe you're probably talking about is really just in the .Net Framework directory. The command prompt of VS just sets up a nice path, but you can launch it from (my path) C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt. You need the **InstallUtil.exe** program which can be found in

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

On x64 machines there's also a 64-bit version in

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727

These directories are obviously only available when .NET is installed.

Answer (score 2):

All that's doing is putting the .Net framework tools onto the PATH; you can go still use:
`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe` by specifying the full path on a normal command prompt (obviously adjust for your framework / CPU architecture)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you're looking for the "installutil.exe" program, which one uses to install .NET Windows Services. You can find it in %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

Answer (score 1):

step 1> Install .net framework (I am using .net 4.0 but you can use as your requirement)

step 2> Go to `run + cmd`  then click ok or directly go to your window command prompt (not visual studio command prompt )

step 3> type these lines

```
> cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
> E:\test\test\bin\Debug\test.exe
```

`E:\test\test\bin\Debug\` is the path where my window service setup is saved

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\` is path where InstallUtil.exe exist.

In both InstallUtil.exe exist. and path must give a space. Otherwise, it raises an error.

Step 4> Enjoy..your service is installed...now you can check it from control panel > administrative tool >Services.

Answer (score 0):

Run CMD as admin

Go to

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>

RUN the following:

InstallUtil C:\Dev\Codebase..\Main\Source....\bin\Debug\.exe

Answer (score 0):

I've found that you can't do this programmically using .Net Core unless you create installers but then its not the program that's installing itself.

But this workaround works using `System.Diagnostics.Process`.  Create a new process that calls your favourite `sc.exe` installation or uninstall command.

i.e.

```
void Install ()
{
    if (Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "sc.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
            process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            process.OutputDataReceived += Process_OutputDataReceived;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
            // use ServiceController from System.ServiceProcess to start, configure the service
        }

        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        // We can't do this as a service...
        Environment.Exit(2);
    }
}
```