# How to install windows service using windows app?

Tags: c#, windows-services, visual-studio-2013

I am pretty new to windows service and I have three projects in my solution:windows app,windows service and a setup and deployment project for the windows service. When the windows app takes an input,I would want the service to start running and perform its own task. However, I do not know how I can install the windows service while I`m still running the windows app. Can this be done by installing windows service programatically via the app? Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072288/installing-windows-service-programmatically

Comment: You might want to read a bit more on Windows Services first before you decide what solution to go for. See [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx) A Service *can* be installed by a forms or CLI app, but if it is supported by an application that only runs part of the time (while the service continues) you are best having it installed along with the supporting application as part of it's setup program, and the supporting app can start/stop the service as needed. Of course without knowing more details I can't say if this will work for you or not!

Comment: Why do you need a service? Why don't you just launch a background process? Or even a separate app that shows no UI?

Comment: Isn`t windows service a background process? And, how do I make a windows metro app without user interface?