# C# Windows Service to programmatically install other windows services

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I have a windows service application that i can install using sc.exe from command line.
I'm trying to create another (manager) service that will check if i have a certain number of instances of the (worker) service running. If not the manager will install the the application how many ever times required with a unique name each time (lets say add random number for now)

I've tried the following

in the manager service have the following:

http://dotnetstep.blogspot.com/2009/06/programmatically-install-window-service.html

but i keep getting 
"Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer '.'. This operation might require other privileges."

i tried 

[Installing Windows Service programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072288/installing-windows-service-programmatically)

but i need to pass in parameters to the worker executable, as well as specify unique servicename and displayname

Not sure what i'm missing here

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.
Turns out i wasn't running VS debug in admin mode.
turning that on got it to work