# How to deploy windows service from Console application using C#

Tags: c#

I created a Windows service using c#.  Using console application I want to deploy this windows service. How this can be achieved using c#. I don't want to use command prompt to install the service.

Comment: Take look at http://topshelf-project.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install a Windows service using a Windows command prompt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164859/install-a-windows-service-using-a-windows-command-prompt)

Comment: @DidierAupest, Can u please try to understand the question first i m not asking using command prompt. please simply dont say its duplicate.

Comment: In fact, you just need to create an application which will need to launch this command lines. Another intesting link is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072288/installing-windows-service-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Install a windows service programmatically use the below code.

I created a class as show below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleServiceCaller
{
    public static class ServiceInstaller
    {
        private const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000;
        private const int SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS = 0x00000010;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private class SERVICE_STATUS
        {
            public int dwServiceType = 0;
            public ServiceState dwCurrentState = 0;
            public int dwControlsAccepted = 0;
            public int dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
            public int dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
            public int dwCheckPoint = 0;
            public int dwWaitHint = 0;
        }

        #region OpenSCManager
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenSCManagerW", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string machineName, string databaseName, ScmAccessRights dwDesiredAccess);
        #endregion

        #region OpenService
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, ServiceAccessRights dwDesiredAccess);
        #endregion

        #region CreateService
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, string lpDisplayName, ServiceAccessRights dwDesiredAccess, int dwServiceType, ServiceBootFlag dwStartType, ServiceError dwErrorControl, string lpBinaryPathName, string lpLoadOrderGroup, IntPtr lpdwTagId, string lpDependencies, string lp, string lpPassword);
        #endregion

        #region CloseServiceHandle
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr hSCObject);
        #endregion

        #region QueryServiceStatus
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        private static extern int QueryServiceStatus(IntPtr hService, SERVICE_STATUS lpServiceStatus);
        #endregion

        #region DeleteService
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool DeleteService(IntPtr hService);
        #endregion

        #region ControlService
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        private static extern int ControlService(IntPtr hService, ServiceControl dwControl, SERVICE_STATUS lpServiceStatus);
        #endregion

        #region StartService
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int StartService(IntPtr hService, int dwNumServiceArgs, int lpServiceArgVectors);
        #endregion

        public static void Uninstall(string serviceName)
        {
            IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.AllAccess);

            try
            {
                IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.AllAccess);
                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new ApplicationException("Service not installed.");

                try
                {
                    StopService(service);
                    if (!DeleteService(service))
                        throw new ApplicationException("Could not delete service " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(service);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scm);
            }
        }

        public static bool ServiceIsInstalled(string serviceName)
        {
            IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.Connect);

            try
            {
                IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.QueryStatus);

                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                    return false;

                CloseServiceHandle(service);
                return true;
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scm);
            }
        }

        public static void InstallAndStart(string serviceName, string displayName, string fileName)
        {
            IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.AllAccess);

            try
            {
                IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.AllAccess);

                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                    service = CreateService(scm, serviceName, displayName, ServiceAccessRights.AllAccess, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, ServiceBootFlag.AutoStart, ServiceError.Normal, fileName, null, IntPtr.Zero, null, null, null);

                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new ApplicationException("Failed to install service.");

                try
                {
                    StartService(service);
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(service);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scm);
            }
        }

        public static void StartService(string serviceName)
        {
            IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.Connect);

            try
            {
                IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.QueryStatus | ServiceAccessRights.Start);
                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new ApplicationException("Could not open service.");

                try
                {
                    StartService(service);
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(service);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scm);
            }
        }

        public static void StopService(string serviceName)
        {
            IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.Connect);

            try
            {
                IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.QueryStatus | ServiceAccessRights.Stop);
                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new ApplicationException("Could not open service.");

                try
                {
                    StopService(service);
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(service);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scm);
            }
        }

        private static void StartService(IntPtr service)
        {
            SERVICE_STATUS status = new SERVICE_STATUS();
            StartService(service, 0, 0);
            var changedStatus = WaitForServiceStatus(service, ServiceState.StartPending, ServiceState.Running);
            if (!changedStatus)
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to start service");
        }

        private static void StopService(IntPtr service)
        {
            SERVICE_STATUS status = new SERVICE_STATUS();
            ControlService(service, ServiceControl.Stop, status);
            var changedStatus = WaitForServiceStatus(service, ServiceState.StopPending, ServiceState.Stopped);
            if (!changedStatus)
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to stop service");
        }

        public static ServiceState GetServiceStatus(string serviceName)
        {
            IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights.Connect);

            try
            {
                IntPtr service = OpenService(scm, serviceName, ServiceAccessRights.QueryStatus);
                if (service == IntPtr.Zero)
                    return ServiceState.NotFound;

                try
                {
                    return GetServiceStatus(service);
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(service);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(scm);
            }
        }

        private static ServiceState GetServiceStatus(IntPtr service)
        {
            SERVICE_STATUS status = new SERVICE_STATUS();

            if (QueryServiceStatus(service, status) == 0)
                throw new ApplicationException("Failed to query service status.");

            return status.dwCurrentState;
        }

        private static bool WaitForServiceStatus(IntPtr service, ServiceState waitStatus, ServiceState desiredStatus)
        {
            SERVICE_STATUS status = new SERVICE_STATUS();

            QueryServiceStatus(service, status);
            if (status.dwCurrentState == desiredStatus) return true;

            int dwStartTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
            int dwOldCheckPoint = status.dwCheckPoint;

            while (status.dwCurrentState == waitStatus)
            {
                // Do not wait longer than the wait hint. A good interval is
                // one tenth the wait hint, but no less than 1 second and no
                // more than 10 seconds.

                int dwWaitTime = status.dwWaitHint / 10;

                if (dwWaitTime < 1000) dwWaitTime = 1000;
                else if (dwWaitTime > 10000) dwWaitTime = 10000;

                Thread.Sleep(dwWaitTime);

                // Check the status again.

                if (QueryServiceStatus(service, status) == 0) break;

                if (status.dwCheckPoint > dwOldCheckPoint)
                {
                    // The service is making progress.
                    dwStartTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
                    dwOldCheckPoint = status.dwCheckPoint;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Environment.TickCount - dwStartTickCount > status.dwWaitHint)
                    {
                        // No progress made within the wait hint
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return (status.dwCurrentState == desiredStatus);
        }

        private static IntPtr OpenSCManager(ScmAccessRights rights)
        {
            IntPtr scm = OpenSCManager(null, null, rights);
            if (scm == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new ApplicationException("Could not connect to service control manager.");

            return scm;
        }
    }


    public enum ServiceState
    {
        Unknown = -1, // The state cannot be (has not been) retrieved.
        NotFound = 0, // The service is not known on the host server.
        Stopped = 1,
        StartPending = 2,
        StopPending = 3,
        Running = 4,
        ContinuePending = 5,
        PausePending = 6,
        Paused = 7
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum ScmAccessRights
    {
        Connect = 0x0001,
        CreateService = 0x0002,
        EnumerateService = 0x0004,
        Lock = 0x0008,
        QueryLockStatus = 0x0010,
        ModifyBootConfig = 0x0020,
        StandardRightsRequired = 0xF0000,
        AllAccess = (StandardRightsRequired | Connect | CreateService |
                     EnumerateService | Lock | QueryLockStatus | ModifyBootConfig)
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum ServiceAccessRights
    {
        QueryConfig = 0x1,
        ChangeConfig = 0x2,
        QueryStatus = 0x4,
        EnumerateDependants = 0x8,
        Start = 0x10,
        Stop = 0x20,
        PauseContinue = 0x40,
        Interrogate = 0x80,
        UserDefinedControl = 0x100,
        Delete = 0x00010000,
        StandardRightsRequired = 0xF0000,
        AllAccess = (StandardRightsRequired | QueryConfig | ChangeConfig |
                     QueryStatus | EnumerateDependants | Start | Stop | PauseContinue |
                     Interrogate | UserDefinedControl)
    }

    public enum ServiceBootFlag
    {
        Start = 0x00000000,
        SystemStart = 0x00000001,
        AutoStart = 0x00000002,
        DemandStart = 0x00000003,
        Disabled = 0x00000004
    }

    public enum ServiceControl
    {
        Stop = 0x00000001,
        Pause = 0x00000002,
        Continue = 0x00000003,
        Interrogate = 0x00000004,
        Shutdown = 0x00000005,
        ParamChange = 0x00000006,
        NetBindAdd = 0x00000007,
        NetBindRemove = 0x00000008,
        NetBindEnable = 0x00000009,
        NetBindDisable = 0x0000000A
    }

    public enum ServiceError
    {
        Ignore = 0x00000000,
        Normal = 0x00000001,
        Severe = 0x00000002,
        Critical = 0x00000003
    }
}
```

Used as below:-

```
 ServiceInstaller.InstallAndStart("testservice", "testingservice", path);
```

Original answer referenced by below post :-

Original Reference : [Installing Windows Service programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072288/installing-windows-service-programmatically)