# How to add your windows service application c# programmatically

Tags: c#, cmd

Normally we do this action with command prompt by admin rights. But you can do this with your application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Windows Service programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072288/installing-windows-service-programmatically)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsServiceUtility
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        bool _correctServiceName = true;
        private string _serviceState;
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnChooseServiceFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dlg = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                Filter = @"Application |*.exe",
                RestoreDirectory = true,
                CheckFileExists = false,
                Title = @"Choose Application.."
            };

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                tbxServicePath.Text = dlg.FileName;
                tbxServiceName.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dlg.FileName);
            }
            _serviceState = CheckServiceState(tbxServiceName.Text);
            lblServiceState.Text = @"Service is " + _serviceState;
            lblServiceState.ForeColor = _serviceState == "Invalid."
                ? Color.Gray
                : _serviceState == "Running"
                    ? Color.Green
                    : Color.DarkRed;
        }

        private string CheckServiceState(string serviceName)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxServiceName.Text.Trim()))
                    return "undefined";
                if (ServiceController.GetServices().FirstOrDefault(record => record.ServiceName == serviceName) == null)
                    _correctServiceName = false; 
                else _correctServiceName = true;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                return "Invalid.";
            }

            if (!_correctServiceName) return "Invalid.";

            var sc = new ServiceController(serviceName);
            using (sc)
            {
                ServiceControllerStatus status;
                try
                {
                    sc.Refresh();
                    status = sc.Status;
                }
                catch (Win32Exception ex)
                {
                    return "Error: " + ex.Message;
                }

                switch (status)
                {
                    case ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
                        return "Running";
                    case ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped:
                        return "Stopped";
                    case ServiceControllerStatus.Paused:
                        return "Paused";
                    case ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending:
                        return "Stopping";
                    case ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending:
                        return "Starting";
                    default:
                        return "Status Changing";
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnCheckServiceState_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _serviceState = CheckServiceState(tbxServiceName.Text);
            lblServiceState.Text = @"Service is " + _serviceState;
            lblServiceState.ForeColor = _serviceState == "Invalid."
                ? Color.Gray
                : _serviceState == "Running"
                    ? Color.Green
                    : Color.DarkRed;
        }

        private void btnInstall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxServicePath.Text.Trim()))
                    throw new Exception("Invalid service path");

                if (_correctServiceName)
                    throw new Exception("Service already installed. You can't install before uninstall this service");

                if (_serviceState == "Running" || _serviceState == "Stopped"
                    || _serviceState == "Paused" || _serviceState == "Stopping"
                    || _serviceState == "Starting" || _serviceState == "Status Changing")
                    throw new Exception("Service already installed. You can't install before uninstall this service");

                InstallUninstallService(true);

                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);

                _serviceState = CheckServiceState(tbxServiceName.Text);
                lblServiceState.Text = @"Service is " + _serviceState;
                lblServiceState.ForeColor = _serviceState == "Invalid."
                    ? Color.Gray
                    : _serviceState == "Running"
                        ? Color.Green
                        : Color.DarkRed;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }
        }

        private void ChangeServiceState(string serviceName, bool start)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo =
                    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                        FileName = "cmd.exe",
                        Verb = "runas",
                        Arguments = "/user:Administrator /K " + (start ? "net start " : "net stop ") + serviceName
                    };
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }
        }

        private void InstallUninstallService(bool install)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo =
                    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                        FileName = "cmd.exe",
                        Verb = "runas",
                        Arguments = "/user:Administrator /K " + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") +
                                    "\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework"
                                    + (cbxPlatform.SelectedText == "X86" ? string.Empty : "64") +
                                    "\\v4.0.30319\\installutil "
                                    + (install ? string.Empty : "/u ") + tbxServicePath.Text.Trim()
                    };
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cxStartAfter.Checked && install)
                    ChangeServiceState(tbxServiceName.Text.Trim(), true);
            }
        }

        private void btnUninstall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxServicePath.Text.Trim()))
                    throw new Exception("Invalid service path");

                if (_serviceState == "Running" || _serviceState == "Stopped"
                    || _serviceState == "Paused" || _serviceState == "Stopping"
                    || _serviceState == "Starting" || _serviceState == "Status Changing")
                {
                    InstallUninstallService(false);

                    Application.DoEvents();

                    Thread.Sleep(5000);

                    _serviceState = CheckServiceState(tbxServiceName.Text);
                    lblServiceState.Text = @"Service is " + _serviceState;
                    lblServiceState.ForeColor = _serviceState == "Invalid."
                        ? Color.Gray
                        : _serviceState == "Running"
                            ? Color.Green
                            : Color.DarkRed;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }
        }

        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cbxPlatform.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While it is appreciated that you posted this, it is just a huge code dump and helps nobody. It would be useful in a blog perhaps, but we like to deal with specific programming problems.

Comment: I have been using this site for a long time, so I do know how it works :) Anyway, you say you didn't find similar code, well someone has already linked a duplicate question, so there it is for you.