# (programmaticaly) self installing a .net core application as a windows service

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-3.1

I like the [generic host feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1) (introduced in asp.net core 3.x), because now you can easily run a web server and background workers within a same process. Furthermore, with a single line, you can with the `.UseWindowsService()` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.windowsservicelifetimehostbuilderextensions.usewindowsservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) to convert this console app into a windows service (with the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices package's extension).
This is very nice!

But in the past, I was used to adding [TopShelf](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf) in my windows services developments, as it did not require me to use the `sc` command, or even the [powershell dedicated commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-service). This was a real simplification for me, but even more for my customers. It really adds value (just tell them `myapp install /option...`).

So my question is: how can I add this kind of feature in the asp.net core >=3.x ecosystem when running on windows? Is there anything existing/planned?

If not, how could I add that? When searching for a solution, I only find [things relying on full .net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2072345/3193607) (4.8 for instance).