# TopShelf- difference between ConfigureServiceInIsolation and ConfigureService

Tags: c#, topshelf

Can someone help me understand this topshelf project...mainly the difference between ConfigureServiceinIsolation and ConfigureService.

http://topshelf-project.com/documentation/getting-started/

It would be nice if someone could point me to some proper documentation about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConfigureServiceInIsolation will run your service in a separate AppDomain within the same process. If you are only running one service, just use ConfigureService.

There is a pretty good example on the link you mentioned and we're always looking for people to help document the project. I admit, the documentation isn't the greatest but basics needed to get started are pretty well spelled out I thought.

Comment: I'm having another problem now after i included your source in my program...please see my question here,...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290437/topshelf-exception