# Topshelf exception

Tags: c#, exception, c#-3.0, casting, topshelf

I'm using [topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) and I'm getting this exception when I try to use the "-i" option to install as a service.

> Unable to cast object of type 'Magnum.CommandLineParser.SwitchElement' to type 'Magnum.CommandLineParser.IArgumentElement'.

Exception occurs in this function

```
static void Set(TopshelfArguments args, 
                IEnumerable<ICommandLineElement> commandLineElements)
{
    var command = commandLineElements
        .Take(1)
        .Select(x => (IArgumentElement) x) //EXCEPTION BREAKS ON THIS LINE
        .Select(x => x.Id)
        .DefaultIfEmpty("commandline")
        .SingleOrDefault();

    args.Command = command;
    //leftovers
    args.CommandArgs = commandLineElements.Skip(1).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way we use TopShelf to install as a service is

```
program.exe service install
```

I believe this is the only way it's supported in the RC code. You can uninstall via

```
program.exe service uninstall
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like when passing in -i that the parser is converting it to a type of SwitchElement. Try this to see if it works.

```
static void Set(TopshelfArguments args, IEnumerable<ICommandLineElement> commandLineElements)
    {
        var command = commandLineElements
            .Take(1)
            .Select(x => (ISwitchElement) x) 
            .Select(x => x.Key)
            .DefaultIfEmpty("commandline")
            .SingleOrDefault();


        args.Command = command;
        //leftovers
        args.CommandArgs = commandLineElements.Skip(1).ToList();
    }
```