# Windows service is not starting automatically after installing

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created a windows service with automatic starting enabled.When i installed the service using installutil it is not starting automatically.But when i tired to start it manually it is working.

When i checked event viewer i couldn't find any error in it.What would be the issue.
How can i find the error?

My start function is like this

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        StartFetch();
    }

    private static void StartFetch()
    {
        try
        {

            FetchManager fetchManager = new FetchManager();
            fetchManager.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;             
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you restart Windows? Autostart starts at windows startup, not automatically after it's installed. Also, if you check the Services in Administrative Tools, does it show it as Manual or Automatic?

Comment: Have you tried attaching to the service with visual studio so you can figure out what is going wrong?  You may be encountering an Exception, but since you're only throwing it back, the service may be swallowing the Exception.  Have you tried putting logging code inside your catch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a .NET Windows Service start right after the installation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195478/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-start-right-after-the-installation)

Comment: If you're set on using InstallUtil to install and start the service, see the accepted answer at the link I provided above.  If you prefer, you can follow the suggestion in my answer to that question to have the service install and start itself via the command line without having to use InstallUtil at all.  That's the way I do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatic Start refers to what happens on a Windows Reboot. It doesn't automatically start the service on install.

To get around this you can of course add a post-installation event to start the service, which is what I do with mine.

There is also the 90's solution of course, ask the user to reboot to complete installation ;-)