# Window Service ProjectInstaller.Install(stateSaver As IDictionary)

Tags: c#, windows, service

I'm not understood what are the actual value of state Saver to pass in ProjectInstaller.Install(stateSaver As IDictionary)

i'm try to install windows service Manually

In My Project add two Item and set all Properties,
1.Service.vb
2.ProjectInstaller.vb

on Button click i'm try to Install Service

```
     Dim projectInstaller As New ProjectInstaller()

     projectInstaller.Install(Nothing)
     projectInstaller.Commit(Nothing)
```

at projectInstaller.Install give me a error 'The stateSaver parameter cannot be null.'

I'm not know, it's possible or not.

Please anybody knows this answer,Help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like:

```
Dim state as new Hashtable();
projectInstaller.Install(state);
projectInstaller.Commit(state);
```

If you really want to make self-installer service, check out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195478/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-start-right-after-the-installation/1195621#1195621). Very useful thing.