# Installing windows service from another app

Tags: c#, windows-services, installation

In my VS solution I have two projects: a windows service and a win app with one form and two buttons (install/uninstall and start/stop). I have followed Matt Davis tutorial

[How to make a .NET Windows Service start right after the installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195478/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-start-right-after-the-installation/1195621#1195621)

for creating ProjectInstaller, now I am confused how to actually fire up installation upon button click, which is in another project (win app). 
Id appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but if you add a reference in the `win app` to `System.Configuration.Install`. This assembly has all the code in the to install services. Then from code in your win app you can add something like this:

```
public void InstallService(string pathToAssembly)
{
    System.Configuration.Install.ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { pathToAssembly });
}
```

To use it, you only need to know the path to the `exe` file of your service that inherits from `ServiceBase`.

Answer (score 0):

My tutorial is geared to install the service from the command line, not from another application.  That said, I think it'd be easy enough to do the following (although I have not tested it):

```
string pathToServiceExecutable = ...;  // specify the full path to your service
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToServiceExecutable, "-install");
```