# Error "Could not find xxxx.Program specified for main method" creating Windows Service from MS example

Tags: .net, windows, c#-4.0, service, windows-services

I am following [this Microsoft guide to create a windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx).

However when I try and build it on the auto generated page called "Program.cs"
That has this code in it

```
namespace BetfairBOTV2Service
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new BrainiacVersion2() // not green though!!!!!
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error "Could not find BrainiacV2.Program" specified for Main Method

I did everything the tutorial told me to.

I have an App.Config, a Program.cs (code above), a BrainiacV2.cs which holds all my code for the service and starts like this

```
namespace BetfairBOTV2Service
{
    public partial class BrainiacV2 : ServiceBase
    {
        public BrainiacV2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
```

My ProjectInstaller.cs with two installer objects on them
(name) serviceInstaller
Display Name: My new BetfairBotV2
ServiceName: BrainiacVersion2

And that is that.

This is the only error I am getting

The solution is called BrainiacV2

I have tried changing the code in Program.cs to

new BrainiacV2()

which turns it green but then I just get

Could not find BrainiacV2.Program specified for main method.

What am I doing wrong or need to change?

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

Win 7, 64 bit, .NET 4.5, C#

Answer (score 58):

After renaming project and default namespace. I also had to change this:

[image]

So in your case at the creation of the project, the default Main was located in BrainiacV2.Program, but you do want to run Main in BetfairBOTV2Service.Program

Comment: So glad you posted this!

Answer (score 2):

I had to change my namespaces and classes around. It was nothing to do with that error (not a very helpful one!)

```
namespace BrainiacV2
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new Brainiac()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

Once I had done that it all worked!

A namespace issue it seems.

Would be nice if the error message was a bit more helpful though, as a lot of guess work was involved!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're specifying the wrong class name.  See the comments below.

```
namespace BetfairBOTV2Service
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new BrainiacVersion2(); // <-- this is what you have
                new BrainiacV2();       // <-- this is what you need
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

FWIW, I have a couple of tutorials - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-for-creating-a-windows-service/593803#593803) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195478/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-start-right-after-the-installation/1195621#1195621) - that show you how to create a service and have it install itself.

HTH

Comment: If u notice my comments in the first code snippet, I tried what u suggested and it goes green (the code) but I get the same error "could not find 'BrainiacV2.Program' specified for Main method

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue some minutes ago, and while searching the web for an explanation, I came across this post. You might have found an answer over the years,
but I'd like to share my solution.
The error arrived at my project when I changed the namespace of the Program class.
By aligning the startup project to the new namespace, my project is working again.

So, in your case, the startup-project should become BetfairBOTV2Service.Program.

Answer (score 0):

IN my case i renamed my solution and many other files and gave this error .
got solved : in csProj file the start-up file still had the older name which was now changed , so after changing it , I was able to build successfully.