# How can I schedule my windows service to run in every ten minutes

Tags: .net, windows-services

I am working in a windows service which downloads data from some devices.How can I schedule my windows service to run in every ten minutes pragmatically.I wanted to download data from these devices in every 10 minutes.Is it a good method to use timer and put the code inside the Elapsed method? Or is there any other method to perform this task?

Comment: Use Windows' Task Scheduler. And please put a little more effort in your question, don't just copy the title and show what you have tried. Are you sure you want your _service to run_ every ten minutes, or do you want it to perform work every ten minutes?

Comment: I wanted to perform the work every ten minutes.

Comment: I think WTS is too heavyweight for this frequency - I'd go for a Windows Service with a timer.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how far you are in the process, but assuming you're just starting, follow the step-by-step instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-for-creating-a-windows-service/593803#593803) to create a basic Windows service that can be installed using the InstallUtil.exe.  If you would prefer to have the Windows service executable install and uninstall itself, follow the step-by-step instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195478/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-start-right-after-the-installation/1195621#1195621).  This should get you started.

Now, to have something run every 10 minutes, you'll need a timer.  Here is an example of what that might look like.

```
using System.Timers;
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private Timer _timer;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(10 * 60 * 1000);  // 10 minutes expressed as milliseconds
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimerElapsed);
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Dispose();
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do your work here...
    }
```

HTH

Comment: You might want to pause/stop the timer when entering the OnTimerElapsed method, and resume it before exiting the method if there is a possibility that your processing could run for more than 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to pause/stop the timer when entering the OnTimerElapsed method, and resume it before exiting the method if there is a possibility that your processing could run for more than 10 minutes.