# Writing Windows service in WCF

Tags: windows, wcf, windows-services

I want to write windows service in wcf After searching a lot I only found were tutorials of writing webservice in wcf not windows service.

Can any one please provide a link to any tutorial which explains how to write windows service in WCF

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Windows Service in WCF" - a Windows service is, roughly, a background task in the windows operating system. WCF is a communications framework so the question as written doesn't make a huge amount of sense.

Comment: Windows Service != WCF Services, Web Services, SOAP Services, etc. Completely different concept. A Windows Service is a long running application that runs in the background. WCF/Web Services pertain to SOA as a way to transport data on networks or even comm between applications running on the same machine (pipes). So.. what are you trying to accomplish? That's the real question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows services are executables. WCF applications are, generally, web services, exposed over a URI. You can host a WCF application within a windows service, not the other way around.

Comment: exactly - you cannot write a Windows service "in WCF" - one can host a WCF service inside a NT Service....

Answer (score 4):

To create a Windows service in C#, follow the step-by-step [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-to-create-a-windows-service/593803#593803).  To make your Windows service WCF-enabled, if you will, create the [`System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) instance that will host your WCF service inside the `OnStart()` callback.

Answer (score 4):

Good answers all of them. Just a quick note... implement your WCF service in a class library (dll) so you can then host it anywhere you like (IIS, Console App, or Windows Service).
I'd recommend starting from a console application, after your service works as expected, create a Windows Service, add a reference to you library and start the service (WCF) from there (Windows Service)

Edit: I just assumed you meant create a WCF service hosted as a Windows Service, if that's not the case please ignore my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create your WCF service as normal, create a Windows Service and then use `ServiceHost` to self-host the WCF service in your Windows Service. See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) for more information about self-hosting WCF services.