# How to start wpf application every time when computer starts?

Tags: wpf, sql-server-ce

I have developed wpf application, in which I have reminder functionality.

Case 1: Current Scenario

Currently I have place my application in startup folder in setup. and application starts whenever my computer starts. But now I have added login functionality so now my client need to login whenever computer starts which is annoying.
According to my functionality, After login into system reminder starts in background.

Case 2: Required

Now what I required is that my application starts in background without login into system, Reminder functionality works as if right now working.

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: If an application starts without a user logging on it has no GUI. I see in your tags that it is a WPF which is a GUI framework. Your program might start but it can't show its graphics.

Comment: Can u explain more, as i can't get u

Answer (score 0):

Starting a program without a user requires it written as a service, or started from one.
There are ways to start an exe file from a service.

Developing a service is basically the same as any other application; but without the GUI. Debugging a service is tedious so you should move the parts you want to execute when running as a service into a DLL. Then you should have an exe to load and execute the methods of the DLL.
This way you have an easy way to debug the functionality of the service; and can have as few times debugging-when-running-as-a-service as possible.

There are certain [caveats when starting and stopping a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692250/installing-windows-service-with-sc-exe-or-installutil-exe-there-is-difference), mainly because the old service wasn't stopped and uninstalled as you supposed.

Tip: [Autorun](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) helps you survey the 4 or more ways to automatically start an application.

How to let a service show a GUI then? I haven't written one myself but found two valid links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5211282/521554) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953148/show-a-windows-form-from-a-window-service).

Comment: As i have already think and test with windows service but i m unable open views from service..