# Communication between windows service and desktop app

Tags: c#, windows-7, named-pipes

I want to create a communication between a windows service and a desktop application on Windows 7.
I read that named pipes are one way for communication between two processes. Can i use them for my purpose?

Comment: That depends, what is your purpose?  What does the app do?  The most common route is a WCF service over HTTP, does that sound suitable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sure you can use named pipes, WCF many other IPC methods.

for named pipe example among stack overflow questions, see here as well for some backgound:

[Inter process communication using Windows service](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3fa1aac8-beba-43f1-9d84-277a1f0f318c/)

also check this one: [GUI and windows service communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773046/gui-and-windows-service-communication)

Comment: The first link didn't really help much, but the second link was pretty informative.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated above, there are lots of options available. Just be aware that if you go the TCP/IP route (e.g. WCF), the user will have to have a valid network connection (a loopback adapter will work) otherwise your client and service won't be able to communicate.

Answer (score 2):

Go with [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119.aspx), it's a good solution to start.