# Communication with .NET service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, ipc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GUI and windows service communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773046/gui-and-windows-service-communication)

What is the most simple local (on one machine) IPC way between a .NET GUI application and a .NET windows service? On the lowest level it should be something like named pipes or local-sockets? Is there any infrastructure for that?

Comment: Is this an existing Windows service, or one that you are creating yourself? Is it on your local domain, over the public internet, behind a firewall? Are you expecting a high volume of traffic between your app and the service (i.e. is performance a significant consideration)?

Comment: It's on only one machine. And it's our own .NET service.

Comment: @OskarKjellin But that's 3 years old.

Comment: @Martin - so why add the complexity of using a separate service at all?

Comment: @RichardEv That's out of question. We need a separate service for many reasons.

Comment: What do you mean by 'simple'? 'Basic', 'Easy to use', ... What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

I would've thought the easiest way to do it is with a web service or RPC/RMC stuff - that way all the communication is done for you.  Im not sure of the details of what classes etc you should be using unfortunately. If you start using sockets you basically have to reinvent the wheel and create you're own way of communicating between the programs, the other two options basically will involve doing a little bit of config and then everything will look like method calls