# What development tools support creation of Windows Services?

Tags: windows-services, devtools

Aside from ActiveState's PerlSvc, what other interpreters and compilers support the development of Windows Services?

Comment: Any environment which allows you to call native modules could be used to create windows services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about Visual Studio .Net?

[Simple Windows Service Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simplewindowsservice.aspx)

[Introduction to Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: +1 - and here's a step-by-step for how to do it using C#...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-to-create-a-windows-service/593803#593803

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio has excellent support for creating services. With a little tweaking you can even debug them. But any compiler can create a service, it's just a matter of accepting certain run parameters that a google search can provide.