# how to call windows service from Webpage hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, windows, iis, windows-services, ipc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to communicate with a windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451216/how-to-communicate-with-a-windows-service)

I have a web page hosted by IIS, from this page after receiving certain user inputs - I would like to pass the values to another windows service. Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: to clarify you want to open a desktop app on the server (where IIS is) or on the clients machine?... e.g. open their Notepad application?

Comment: I'm not sure if it deserved to be closed just yet... so here is your chance to clarify the question: please add information of what machines run IIS, "web page" (and if it rendered by a browser or custom code), and "desktop application" - is it the same one, two or maybe even 3 machines. Also add a note if you are targeting internet/intranet and browser versions.

Comment: Please read your question as if someone else asked it. "web page hosted by IIS" and "same machine" - same as what: web page and service, IIS and service, all 3?

Comment: No, I'm hosting a webPage in IIS which need to pass values to another windows service.

Comment: This is a legit question (though research seems lacking) but the duplicate explains it enough to get started. I'd suggest hosting a WCF endpoint inside a Windows service and adding it as a service reference to the web app.