# Windows background service to kill processes by name on demand

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, service

I want to write a simple background service that can kill all instances of a certain process for all users on demand. The process will always be the same (Microsoft Access). The idea is that users without administrative rights are able to execute a script, which tells the background service to kill the processes before moving on with other tasks. I do have a small program written in C which is able to kill all processes when executed from the Local System account, but I'm not sure how to turn it into a service that can be triggered on demand. Any suggestions are welcome. Also, I'm open for any other way of killing all instances of a process for all users without administrative rights.

Comment: I haven't done it, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18637556/5095502) looks like a simple way to talk to a service. Instead of running a "script", you will have to write a very small second program that sends the `sc.ExecuteCommand()` to your service.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a service from an executable using a tool such as **SrvStart** (you can find on [this page](http://www.rozanski.org.uk/software)) and the windows command line tool `sc.exe`. [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/) is a tutorial that will help you to do so.

In order to "talk" to the service, you will need to implement some inter-process communication mechanism so that a client (script or so) runned with user priviledge ask the service to do the job. There are plenty of ways to do this... See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx) for what you can use.

Another way is to get rid of your C executable and make a windows .NET service in C# instead. In this service, override the [ServiceBase.OnCustomCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.oncustomcommand.aspx). Then you will be able to send a custom command to your service using the windows command line tool `sc.exe`.

On the other hand, if what you need is only to run an executable with administrator priviledge from a user account, without password, there is a way to create a shortcut that does this. See [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/124087/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-lets-a-standard-user-run-an-application-as-administrator/) for details on how to make such a shortcut.

Comment: Thanks. My executable only works when executed by Local System, because otherwise it will only terminate processes owned by the account from which the executable is executed. I will look into your other suggestions!