# OPOS library v1.14 is not working as expected with x64 build of .net

Tags: x86, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, winforms-interop, opos

We are using the OPOS drivers v 1.11 in our Desktop application and now migrating it to v 1.14.
The application is working fine with the newer version on x86 architecture but when compiled to x64 , it throws a runtime error for class not registered.
The exception is encountered on the very first attempt to initialize a new instance of the object class.
When called for new instance,

```
oPOSPOSPrinter = new OPOSPOSPrinter();
```

The exception thrown is,

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>     HResult=0x80040154
>     Message=Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {CCB90152-B81E-11D2-AB74-0040054C3719} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
>     Source=mscorlib

The dlls we are refencing here is a 32 bit version & our application is compiled on 64 bit.

We tried to register it via regsvr32 tool but then it throws an exception there as well.

[image]

We tried to manually add it to the registry but it didn’t helped.

We tried with both the versions, one from the default OPOS installation directory & another from the OposFor.Net folder in the same directory.

So, we would like to ask for a solution as to how to achieve this?
We want to migrate our application on x64 architecture and support all the current functionality from the OPOS v 1.11 on OPOS v 1.14.
Also, will there be a 64-bit version of the OPOS drivers available in near future?

System & App Info:
OS: Windows 10 Pro
IDE: VS 2017,
.Net Version: .Net 4 +
OPOS dll Version: 1.14.001

Comment: Is this .Net application or native Win32/64?

Comment: this one is a .net winform application built on .net 4 + version

Comment: OPOS is 32-bit. I am not sure whether it is impossible to call it from 64-bit App but it is easier to compile your application with Target = x86 or create x86 intermediate program which is controlled by 64-bit.

Comment: PS: Try this https://techtalk.gfi.com/32bit-object-64bit-environment/ and write here if it is working :)

Comment: BTW: Since "Official versions of software" exists only in 32 bit environment, if you want to work with it, there is only the method of "1." shown in my answer. Please establish the communication between the 64bit process and the 32bit process freely inside the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

64 Bit process cannot call a 32bit library directly in it's process. You need to have a different approach to talk to 32 Bit library.

- Create a seperate 32 Bit exe which will be doing what you want to
  achieve using that 32 Bit library, and call that exe from your 64 Bit process and by passing the right parameters based on which you can identify the call and it's action and you can return the desired output to your process.
- You can as well create a WebSocket based client/server application and can
  communicate with your 64 Bit process, which can be a much faster
  approach then a exe
- Alternativly you can as well create a WCF service where you can use
  your 32 Bit dll and consume that WCF service in your 64 Bit
  Application and be done with that.

**Note:** If the communication need to happen on the same machine (means your 64 Bit application and 32 Bit library is going to be in the same machine) in this case first two options will be the best work with.

Hope this info helps and can help you procees further.

Happy Coding...

Comment: That's a viable solution. Thanks @abhinav

Answer (score 2):

UnifiedPOS(including OPOS) specification supports only 32 bit.

[Download the current version 1.14.1 of UnifiedPOS](https://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?retail/2017-07-32)
Page A-1

> The goals of OLE for Retail POS (or "OPOS") include:
>   - Defining an architecture for Win32-based POS device access.
>   - Defining a set of POS device interfaces sufficient to support a range of POSsolutions.

Page A-3

> A CO is a standard ActiveX (that is, OLE 32-bit) Control that is invisible at runtime.

Common CO only supports 32 bit.
[MCS: OPOS Common Control Objects - Current Version](http://monroecs.com/oposccos_current.htm)

I experimentally created Common CO that supports 64 bit, but this is informal.
[kunif/OPOS-CCO](https://github.com/kunif/OPOS-CCO)

If you use OPOS as a service object in POS for.NET, you need to operate it with 32 bit.

For 32 bit exe/dll which runs in 64 bit OS, corresponding registry data is separated under WOW6432Node in varius places.
However, some registries are separated by 64/32, some registries are linked with 64/32, and so on.

Although device vendors may support 64 bit independently, it is considered to be few.

The following suggestions are possible.

1. Divide the application into two or more processes and link them through interprocess communication.
   Main application running at 64 bit process.
   I/O control(OPOS) application operating at 32 bit process.
2. Use only vendor equipment and OPOS that independently support 64bit.
3. Use 32 bit OPOS from a 64 bit application, using techniques such as those described in the comments.

---

**In Addition:**
Supplementary information on the method of "3." is as follows.

[DLL Surrogates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/dll-surrogates)
[DLL Server Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/dll-server-requirements)
[Using the System-Supplied Surrogate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/using-the-system-supplied-surrogate)
[Writing a Custom Surrogate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/writing-a-custom-surrogate)

> Interfaces that aren't remotable (such as those for recent OCXs) will not work with the system surrogate. A custom surrogate could wrap the DLL's interfaces with its own implementation and use proxy/stub DLLs with a remotable IDL definition that would allow the interface to be remoted.

[Accessing 32-bit DLLs from 64-bit code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39948944/9014308) in StackOverflow Article
[Accessing 32-bit DLLs from 64-bit code](https://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/) Original Article

[How do I make COM Surrogate Multiple Instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54444548/9014308)
[Hosting a .NET DLL as an Out-Of-Process COM Server (EXE)](https://dzone.com/articles/hosting-net-dll-out-process)
[DllSurrogate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/com/dllsurrogate)
[REGCLS Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/ne-combaseapi-tagregcls)