# Windows service and sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite, windows-services

If I have PHP with SQLite configured as database installed in a windows box, what steps should I follow to build a windows service that - among other things - reads and updates data from that db ?

Where is the db file located ? Which path is more recommended for sqlite integration: C or .net (C#) ? Any caveats ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-for-creating-a-windows-service/593803#593803

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where is db file located, but for creating windows service, you should be able to use C, C++ or C# (Or any other .Net language).

I find you can use a [library](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) here to work with SQLite.

Since the service will run on the background all the time, just make sure that you don't use or leak any resource , otherwise, you are affecting the whole machine performance.