# How to run bat file as Windows service

Tags: c#, batch-file, service

I have a bat file in which I have called a simple console application in c#. Whenever I run the bat file it displays the console and run. Can any one tell me how to run bat file as windows service so that to avoid this

Comment: Have you tried adding runas /user:domain\user "YourConsoleFilePathAndFileName" to the batch file?

Comment: Please prevent this from being an XY problem, where X is _"I want to do something"_ and Y is your perceived solution to problem X: _"So I need to run this batch file as a Windows Service"_. You don't want this. You can use SrvAny to create a Windows Service from any application, but you really don't want to. Explain us your original problem X. Probably you're looking for a Scheduled Task, for example.

Comment: Hai CodeCaster. I want the bat file to run in background even though after signing out from the user account

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

[Running a C# console application as a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222020/running-a-c-sharp-console-application-as-a-windows-service)

It's not straightforward due to the fact that console app doesn't automatically qualify as a service, you will have to do some coding.

By the sound of your post though it seems as if you initially wanted to build a service in the first place, in that case, start from scratch and [make a Windows service](https://www.google.rs/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=pdT-VLS3J7e1sQTjioKgDw#q=developing+windows+service+in+c%23).