# Adding a service installer and service process installer in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-services, service-installer

For some reason, after adding a Installer class to my Windows Service project, I open it up in design mode and right click, but there is no option to add either a service installer or a service process installer.  Does anyone know why this may be the case?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In both Visual Studio 2008 and 2010, the best way to do this is to open the `ServiceBase` component (named `Service1` by default) in design mode.  Then, right-click in the designer and select the *Add Installer* option.  This adds a `ProjectInstaller` component along with the necessary assembly references.  The `ProjectInstaller` component, in turn, has the service installer and service process installer added automatically.

Without additional detail, my best guess is that you manually added a component/class to your project and named it `Installer` instead of letting Visual Studio do the work for you.

See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-for-creating-a-windows-service/593803#593803) for how to create a basic service in Visual Studio 2008 (seems to work in 2010 as well).  Pay particular attention to Step 6.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem to the one in the question, only it seems I can't go through step 6. I manually added the windows service template to VC# studio express - do I have to install the proper installer components before the menu option shows up for the studio express?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the VS Express editions don't natively support creation of Windows services.  You'll probably have to do everything manually; that has been my limited experience with those products.

Comment: Can use ServiceInstaller or ProjectInstaller to do something like `MyService.exe install` or `MyService.exe uninstall`? It looks like they are only used by external tools. I want my service to (un)install by passing arguments to the service itself, not `InstallUtil`