# Windows service status stays at starting for ever even when it has actually started

Tags: c#, windows-services

I followed the instructions in the marked answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-for-creating-a-windows-service/593803#593803) to create a service. The service gets installed correctly. When I start the service after a while it throws a message 
"Windows could not start the xxx service on Local Computer.

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
"

After I click ok, its status stays at "Starting" for ever. When I checked the application and system logs, there were no errors.

When I check the SQL trace, the service is actually running correctly and doing what its supposed to do. So why does its status stay at "Starting" ?

Update:
This is the code in OnStart method

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            Loader loader = new Loader();
            loader.StartProcess();
        }
```

Update 2:

based on WiktorZychla's comment I did this and it worked :)

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            Loader loader = new Loader();

            ThreadStart threadDelegate = new ThreadStart(loader.StartProcess);
            Thread newThread = new Thread(threadDelegate);
            newThread.Start();

        }
```

Comment: What is in your on start? Are you spinning? Locking? Waiting? In other words: does the OnStart method ever finish?

Comment: If the `loader.StartProcess` never returns, you have what you see. In OnStart you should rather start a new thread and the method should return just after.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: If I start a new thread on OnStart, do I need to do a thread.abort on OnStop?

Comment: Yes, you do need to do that (sorry for the verbose comment but comments shorter than 15 characters are disallowed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on WiktorZychla's comment this is what I did

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using IndexLoader;
using System.Threading;

namespace myNameSpace
{
    public partial class LoaderService : ServiceBase
    {
        Thread newThread;
        public LoaderService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            Loader loader = new Loader();

            ThreadStart threadDelegate = new ThreadStart(loader.StartProcess);
            newThread = new Thread(threadDelegate);
            newThread.Start();

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if ((newThread != null) && (newThread.IsAlive))
            {


                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                newThread.Abort();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It would be instructive to know exactly what is in your `OnStart()` method.  The `OnStart()` method is a callback from the OS that is used to start your service, but it **must** return within 30 seconds or so (I remember reading that somewhere).  Otherwise, the OS gives the message you're seeing.  In short, limit the `OnStart()` method to getting things initialized, and defer the actual work your service is to perform to a thread of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

In your Program.cs file in the `Main()` function make sure that you have:

`ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceClassHere());`

I've been guilty many times when creating a windows form app of keeping

`Application.Run(new Class());` in my `Main()` function