# Writing Windows C++ server as service or console application

Tags: c++, windows, windows-services, client-server, console-application

This requires discussion for best practices related to server development using C++ on Windows 7 32-bit

The typical requirements:

1. A program that acts like a "server", running in Windows in the background. It should run for days, should run automatically at each start.
2. Server Handles incoming client connections via TCP socket protocol from other devices (PC,Smartphone,tablets)
3. Server in-turn communicating with large number of embedded devices connected in same network via TCP and serial communications
4. Server acting as bridge b/w clients (PC, smartphone, tablets) and embedded devices

The server admin can configure server through the configuration .ini file and then can start server.

The interface to the client end is TCP socket interface, client will send command and server inturn will reply with buffer (xml)
My questions:

1. Should I write the program as a "service", like http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsService-cacf4948
2. Or should i write a console application and control this executable from XYNTService http://mysite.verizon.net/XiangYangL/XYNTService.htm so that it acts like a service
3. Or a console application , with it's entry in registry for starting at login, restart

Does this actually matter, which option to choose from above ?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it quacks like a service then it is a service. You haven't specified any interaction with user, which is most important factor in "is it a service" question IMHO. The page about XYNT targets NT4.0, so I suspect it's about 16 years old. No point in archeology.

Comment: Like a service.  But a command line option to run like a console app may be useful for development and debugging efficiency.

Comment: I agree with @selbie. I have wrote many services and I couldn't imagine any other way of working efficiently.

Comment: so, initially we should make console executable and later on we enable the service module in the same.  I mean making code in such a way that it can act as a executable while debugging and service while deploying. ?

Comment: Gets my vote; Console app with command line to enable it otherwise it becomes a service.

Comment: Is there a pressing need to write this in C++?  It'd be a lot easier in C#.  Perhaps a bit self-serving, but here you go:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-for-creating-a-windows-service/593803#593803

Comment: @Marc Gravell provides some key insights for installing and executing a C#-based service here:  https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/TUXp6lRxy6Q

Comment: currently preferring C++ as we might shift to linux later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly the use case for which services are intended, so make it a service.

For easier debugging, add a command line option to start it as a console process.

Comment: Made it Community Wiki as I'm essentially only summarizing the answers that were already given in the comments.