# How to Windows Service insert data to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services

I'm beginner to windows service. I want to build a windows service that insert data to sql server scheduled. Anyone could help me how to program this task.

Comment: Your question is not clear! Would you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks Adel Khayata! I mean that: Each 2 minutes windows service will insert a time value in sql database. Sorry about my bad English :v

Answer (score 3):

Here is a:

[step-by-step procedure for creating a Windows service in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-for-creating-a-windows-service/593803#593803)

Accessing SQL Database from windows service has the same code that is used for normal applications.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to think about a sql agent job. SQL Agent is a service that comes bundled with MS SQL server and allows you to perform a mirad of tasks on a scheduled basis. It is much easier than crafting your own windows service and it doesn't require a formal installer to get it going.