# How to install VS2012 Windows Service without using installutil.exe

Tags: .net, windows, service, windows-services, installation

I am trying to install a windows service without using the installutil. An understandable and straightforward way to do this which I found is to use:

> ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper

So I end up with the following Program.cs:

```
 static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length >0)
        {
            string parameter = string.Concat(args);
            switch (parameter)
            {
                case "--install":
                    ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                    break;
                case "--uninstall":
                    ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new PicknikService() 
            };
           ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

After I Build the service and execute MyService.exe --install I get the following:

```
Cannot start service from the command line or debugger. A winwows Service must first be installed(using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Afministrative tool or the NET START command.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible way seems to be the [following](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sachin.nigam/InstallingWinServiceProgrammatically11262005061332AM/InstallingWinServiceProgrammatically.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.managedinstallerclass.installhelper.aspx) for `ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper` says the following:

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not
>   intended to be used directly from your code.

While I have no doubt the solution offered at the link you provided will do the trick, it makes heavy use of P/Invoke calls.  There's nothing wrong with that, but I prefer a fully C#-based solution.

I have such a solution in a step-by-step tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593454/easiest-language-for-creating-a-windows-service/593803#593803) for creating a Windows service that will install and uninstall itself from the command line without requiring InstallUtil.exe.  It was written for Visual Studio 2008, but it still works as I've since written a service that does the same thing in Visual Studio 2012.